# OpenCV on android, Mat.rows() = 0

Tags: opencv, android

I have an Uri pointing to an image I have chosen. I want to store the image in a Mat variable, edit it and show it in an ImageView. Till now, I just want to load the image in the Mat variable, and show it, without edits. This is my code:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(uri.getPath());

//several edits in future

Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.rows(), image.cols(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(image, resultBitmap);
imageView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
```

The line that gives the error is `Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.rows(), image.cols(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`, and says that `image.rows()` and `image.cols()` cannot be `0`.

It's logic that if the dimensions are (0, 0) it gives an error, but I can't figure out why they are 0.

Comment: Most likely `imread` failed, since when that happens it returns an empty image.

Comment: How can I know that? And how should I move to try to fix it? Thanks, Lorenzo

Comment: Call the [`empty`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#empty--) method of the `Mat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was passing a wrong URI to `imread`, which therefore failed and returned an empty Mat. As [Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) suggested I've called the `empty` method, that returned `true`, and I found that I was passing a wrong URI.